# Ehcache cached item is wrong

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I use hibernate + ehcache to read a workflow engine database.
hibernate does not write anything on that database.
If i set TimetoLive setting in the cache, the cache won't reflect any database changes unless TimetoLive arrives.

database changes is done by the workflow engine API, so there is no way to use hibernate to write the database.

Shouldn't ehcache knows the cache is expired and do the updates for me ?

Any clean way to solve the cache wrong problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the cache won't reflect any database changes unless TimetoLive arrives.

That's the intended functionality! These second level caches do nothing but store data in hash maps and know nothing about the changes unless you tell it to or the time to evict the objects out of cache and reread them.

To solve this is to not use caches on volatile objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, since i will not manually invalidate the cache in my business logic, i won't use cache in the workflow database. Instead, i will just use the cache in my database only.

Comment: if you find performance to be unacceptable without the cache (this is rarely the case) you can look into cache replication strategies like gemfire, terracota, coherance

Answer (score 0):

> If i set TimetoLive setting in the cache, the cache won't reflect any database changes unless TimetoLive arrives.

So that means you are not using it.

> database changes is done by the workflow engine API, so there is no way to use hibernate to write the database.

So as an laternative (to timetoLive), that means you need cache mode to read-write or read-nonstrictly-write (check the name something like that). If its not reflecting the chnages and I am asssuming two things

1. Your workflow Engine is using hibernate
2. And your cache setting is read-only

Comment: Thanks for your reply, hibernate is read only, and cache is set to read only also, so the timestampcache will never updates, that makes the problem. I will not use ehcache on the workflow database.